# JMeter Recorder is not working with HTTPS

Tags: ssl, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

Please before you say this has been asked on stack overflow, I have looked at each one of the answers and none of them are working as a solution.

No matter what I do HTTPS websites not working with JMeter recorder.

Using FireFox 63.03
Using JMeter 5.0
Mac OS

Here are my steps: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amEHuq8auTU)

```
1). Create New Test Plan
2). Added a thread group
3). Added HTTP(S) recorder
4). Using port 8282 (tried 8080 earlier so trying others)
5). redirect automatically, follow redirects checked
6). Select HTTPS test script recorder for target controller
7) Add the HTTPS site (without the https)
8). Click Start
9). Getting prompted that ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt is created
10. Triple checked that all previous ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt are deleted in firefox cert settings
11). Install the new certificate with the two permissions checked (identify websites, identify users)
12). Now when I go to the site that I added in step 7. I get :
jmeter SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG in the browser.
```

When I check the jmeter logs:

I get:

```
2018-11-23 13:14:48,287 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [50795]  KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host 'blue.mysite.com' in map with key (blue.mysite.com)
2018-11-23 13:14:48,308 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.h.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory: Setting up HTTPS TrustAll Socket Factory
2018-11-23 13:14:48,313 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS
2018-11-23 13:14:48,313 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread
2018-11-23 13:14:48,326 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location:  type JKS
2018-11-23 13:14:48,326 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2018-11-23 13:14:48,327 WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore
2018-11-23 13:14:49,606 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [50788]  KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host 'www.google.com' in map with key (www.google.com)
2018-11-23 13:14:49,613 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [50788]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'www.google.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: readHandshakeRecord
2018-11-23 13:14:49,613 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [50790]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'www.google.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: readHandshakeRecord
2018-11-23 13:14:49,613 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [50789]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'www.google.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: readHandshakeRecord
2018-11-23 13:14:56,059 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: [50805]  Creating entry getpocket.cdn.mozilla.net in /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/libexec/bin/proxyserver.jks
2018-11-23 13:14:59,048 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [50805]  KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host 'getpocket.cdn.mozilla.net' in map with key (getpocket.cdn.mozilla.net)
2018-11-23 13:14:59,184 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy:
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
```

I have done this a lot of times and have played around with settings. Nothing seems to work. I even switched the url to 'https://yahoo.com' and to another personal site 'https://lawyeranalytix.com' thinking maybe the site I am trying to test has a flawed SSL implementation but it is the same with any SSL enabled site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'www.google.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert

It appears that you failed to install JMeter's certificate to Firefox.

Try [clearing your Firefox history](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox) and ensure to delete everything from the beginning of the time - it will include custom certificates. Restart Firefox once done.

Check out the following materials:

- **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) user manual chapter
- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)

Also be aware of the alternative ways of recording a JMeter test:

- [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en)
- [Using Badboy with JMeter](http://www.badboysoftware.biz/docs/jmeter.htm)

Answer (score 14):

There seems to be an issue between the JMeter proxy recorder and TLS 1.4. I solved the issue by limiting the Firefox TLS version to 1.3.

To do this :

- Go to `about:config` in Firefox
- Set `security.tls.version.fallback-limit` and `security.tls.version.max` to 3.

Then I was able to record as expected.

Comment: This option worked for me. Same thing if you doing recording for burp suite or OwaspZap. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thank you, it works with Jmeter 5.11 / Mozilla Firefox 76

Comment: This solved my issues with some JavaScript files not loading! JMeter 5.4.1.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to downgrade to oracle java jdk 10, it solved the problem for me.

for further reference:

https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/questions/17434431-gettin-error-code-ssl-error-rx-record-too-long

EDIT: or use openjdk 8

Comment: Thanks for this. Downgrading to OpenJDK 8 made my issues go away.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the expired certificate.
2. Import new certificate from bin folder.
3. Verify certificate date is valid.
   Then you will be able to work with HTTPS.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer